# How to check is Location Services enabled in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to check is Location Services enabled or disabled in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;

Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
if (locator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
{
    // Location is turned off
}
```

Plus the `PositionStatus` enumeration also has several values like :

```
Ready, NoData, Initializing, Disabled, NotInitialized, NotAvailable.
```

Hope this helps you.
Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public bool IsLocationServiceEnabled
  {
   get
   {
     Geolocator locationservice = new Geolocator();
     if (locationservice.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
     {
      return false;
     }
     return true;
   }
  }
```

[How to Find if the Location Services are Turned Off](http://mobileosgeek.com/how-to-find-if-the-location-services-are-turned-off-in-windows-phone-using-c/)